# No clue how to download Skype onto Asus 1015e

Tags: skype, asus, downloads

I recently bought an Asus 1015e, but I have no idea how to correctly download Skype. Help!

Comment: Is your Asus running on Ubuntu? Have you searched for Skype in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to download Skype:

[Skype Download](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/)

Remember to choose your distribution